# Can't calculate matrix exponential in python

Tags: python, scipy, jax

I want to calculate:

```
from jax.scipy.linalg import expm
import jax.numpy as jnp
from functools import lru_cache, reduce

num_qubits=2
theta = jnp.asarray(np.pi*np.random.random((15,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)))

def pauli_matrix(num_qubits):
    _pauli_matrices = jnp.array(
    [[[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, -1j], [1j, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, -1]]]
    )
    return reduce(jnp.kron, (_pauli_matrices for _ in range(num_qubits)))[1:]

def SpecialUnitary(num_qubits,theta):
    assert theta.shape[0] == 15
    A = jnp.tensordot(theta, pauli_matrix(num_qubits), axes=[[0], [0]])
    print(f'{A.shape= }{pauli_matrix(num_qubits).shape=}{theta.shape=}')
    return expm(1j*A/2)

SpecialUnitary(num_qubits,theta)
```

Shapes: `A.shape= (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4)pauli_matrix(num_qubits).shape=(15, 4, 4)theta.shape=(15, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)`
Error: `ValueError: expected A to be a square matrix`

I'm stuck because the documentation says that the expm is calculated on the last two axes, which must be square, which is done.

Comment: The provided code works for me with no errors, jax version 0.4.23

Comment: You're probably using an old version of JAX that was released before [this PR](https://github.com/google/jax/commit/ad0fc8979b0e656cb8901dfa1a4050432ed86892) that implemented batched inputs for expm

Comment: @Nin17 yeah, thanks! It's works after upgrading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batched `expm` is supported in recent JAX versions, and you should find that this works fine in JAX v0.4.7 or newer:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.scipy.linalg

X = jnp.arange(128.0).reshape(2, 2, 2, 4, 4)

result = jax.scipy.linalg.expm(X)
print(result.shape)
# (2, 2, 2, 4, 4)
```

If for some reason you must use an older JAX version, you can work around this by using [`jax.numpy.vectorize`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.vectorize.html). For example:

```py
expm = jnp.vectorize(jax.scipy.linalg.expm, signature='(n,n)->(n,n)')

result = expm(X)
print(result.shape)
# (2, 2, 2, 4, 4)
```